# check whether array contains every element of another array or not

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if given array contains every single element of second array for example

```
['Laptop', 'PC', 'Ipad', 'Telephone', 'Smart Watch']
['Laptop,' 'PC', 'Smart Watch'] //true
['Laptop', 'Ipad', 'Banana'] //false
```

I tried this code:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var check = [3, 4, 5];

    var found = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
          if (arr.indexOf(check[i]) > -1) {
             found = true;
             break;
          }
      }
    alert(found);
```

It works but not as i want, it alerts true even if only one element from child is found in parent array. so how can i implement what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const check = (a, b) => b.every(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a));

var array1 = ['Laptop', 'PC', 'Ipad', 'Telephone', 'Smart Watch'],
    array2 = ['Laptop', 'PC', 'Smart Watch'],
    array3 = ['Laptop', 'Ipad', 'Banana'];

console.log(check(array1, array2)); //  true
console.log(check(array1, array3)); // false
```

ES5 (IE safe)

```js
function check(a, b) {
    var items = a.reduce(function (o, v) {
            o[v] = true;
            return o;
        }, Object.create(null));
    return b.every(function (v) { return items[v]; });
}

var array1 = ['Laptop', 'PC', 'Ipad', 'Telephone', 'Smart Watch'],
    array2 = ['Laptop', 'PC', 'Smart Watch'],
    array3 = ['Laptop', 'Ipad', 'Banana'];

console.log(check(array1, array2)); //  true
console.log(check(array1, array3)); // false
```

Comment: Yeah i knew about Set, but since i want to use this code in my server side code for validation and Set is only supported above IE11, i resist to use it. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var check = [3, 4, 5];
var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
      found =arr.indexOf(check[i]) > -1 ? true : false
  }
alert(found);
```

Comment: this code seems to be good but if you check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/347wyaoc/) 
you should notice that it must not log true in this case

Comment: yeah it doesn't.... run the snippet.. I put there.... it will only log true if all the item in the child array is present in the parent array..
i.e arr[] and check[]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to iterate the 2nd array, and check with [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (or [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for old browsers) if the item exists in the 1st array. The every method will return `false` if any check includes check fails, and `true` if all succeed.

```js
const contains = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr2.every(v => arr1.includes(v)); // or arr2.every(v => arr1.indexOf(v) !== -1) for IE

console.log(contains(['Laptop', 'PC', 'Ipad', 'Telephone', 'Smart Watch'], ['Laptop', 'PC', 'Smart Watch'])); // true

console.log(contains(['Laptop', 'PC', 'Ipad', 'Telephone', 'Smart Watch'], ['Laptop', 'Ipad', 'Banana'])); // false

console.log(contains([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])); // false
```

Comment: You probably mean `includes` doesn't work in IE, but where is IE mentioned in his question?

Comment: Thanks. Added indexOf option.

Comment: It works fine. You forgot to return the results of the function - https://jsfiddle.net/m4aongpu/.